# Как в 1С помощью цикла правильно вывести строки в excel?

Tags: циклы, 1с

Код цикла в 1С:

```
МассивК = Новый Массив();
МассивК.Добавить(111);
МассивК.Добавить(222);
МассивК.Добавить(333);

Для Каждого ЭлементМассива из МассивК Цикл //Здесь элементы 111,222,333

    Для Счетчик = 2 По МассивК.Количество()+1 Цикл //Здесь по идее по циклу подставляются номера строк      
        
        Лист.Cells(Счетчик, 1).Value = ЭлементМассива; //Подставляем номер строки Счетчик и значение ЭлементМассива
        
    КонецЦикла; //Здесь по идее по циклу подставляются номера строк
    
КонецЦикла; //Здесь элементы 111,222,333
```

Который по идее должен вывести в одном столбце строки:

```
111
222
333
```

Но почему-то выводится так:

```
333
333
333
```

Как сделать так, чтобы в excel записался:

```
111
222
333
```

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендую вам для понимания своей ошибки разобрать свой алгоритм "по косточкам". Взять листок бумаги, ручку. Пошагово идти и записывать что будет в переменных.

Вариантов решения много. Советую самому еще раз вникнуть и попробовать исправить, прежде чем смотреть ответ.

Можно так:

> `НомерСтроки = 2;`
>  `Для каждого ЭлементМассива Из МассивК Цикл`
>      `Лист.Cells(НомерСтроки, 1).Value = ЭлементМассива;`
>      `НомерСтроки = НомерСтроки + 1;`
>  `КонецЦикла;`